# How to calculate average per row (awk command)

Tags: awk, sed, row, average, calculator

I have a file with 269 countries.
 10 columns each country. 
I need to create a script that will average calculation of Japan  from the 5-10 column and save the average in a new file 
like : 
*Japan,JPN,Forest area (% of land area)= "(The average number)".*

My file is. Csv
I don't need all the country average. I just want to calculate average of Japan.

```
Jordan,JOR,Forest area (% of land area),AG.LND.FRST.ZS,1.0982203199,1.0982203199,1.0982203199,1.0982203199,1.0982203199,1.0982203199,,
Japan,JPN,Forest area (% of land area),AG.LND.FRST.ZS,68.4844328624,68.4791046618,68.4737766074,68.4693877551,68.4649989028,68.4606100505,,
Kazakhstan,KAZ,Forest area (% of land area),AG.LND.FRST.ZS,1.2256917435,1.2256917435,1.2256917435,1.2256917435,1.2256917435,1.2256917435,,
```

Comment: What information other than the average needs to be in the new file? Please edit your question to show the desired output based on your sample input.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
Hope everything is clear now

Comment: No, edit your question to show **the desired output** based on your sample input, not just a description of how you'd like to arrive at some values.

Comment: We'll help you fix your code, but we won't do it for you. Plase show you best attempt to solve your problem and we'll help you understand where you turned the wrong corner. Good luck.

Comment: tags on StackOverflow are mostly about "subscribers" to tags. You want readers who "watch" for `awk` tags to read your Q. We don't care about row, average, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
awk -v country=Japan 'BEGIN{FS=","}{ if( $1==country ) { n=0; for(i=5;i<NF;++i) { if( $i ) { ++n; sum += $i; } } print country ": " sum/n; }}' infile.txt
```

Variable `country` can be set at wish. The fields from 6 to end are summed up and divided by the number of entries to get the avarage.